# C# using db context and exception handling in a better way (DRY)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I am writing this piece of code in the given action of WEP API controller in all my action methods in web API controllers I am making resulting in a lot of code redundancy and repeating my self (!DRY) hence i need a way this can be done with a better approach using inheritance or iterface or by using any other object oriented approach.

```
[Route("myApiGetRequest")]
[HttpGet]
public IHttpActionResult myApiGetRequest(long id)
{
    try
    {
        DataTable transaction = new DataTable();
        using (var context = new myDbContext())
        {
            //code for what I want to do

        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return Ok(new { success = false, message = ex.Message });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can take advantage of exception filters which are available in `WebApi`. Then, move exception handling code to that filter.

For instance:

```
public class MyExceptionFilterAttribute : ExceptionFilterAttribute 
{
    public override void OnException(HttpActionExecutedContext context)
    {
        if (context.Exception is Exception)
        {
            context.Response = new HttpResponseMessage { Content = new StringContent("Exception occured", System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, "text/plain"), StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError};
        }
    }
}
```

And then in your `WebApi` controller you can do following:

```
[Route("myApiGetRequest")]
[HttpGet]
[MyExceptionFilter]
public IHttpActionResult myApiGetRequest(long id)
{
    DataTable transaction = new DataTable();
    using (var context = new myDbContext())
    {
         //code for what I want to do

    }
}
```

Exceptions which then will occur in your `myApiGetRequest` will be handled by corresponding exception filter which this method is decorated

Answer (score 2):

ExceptionHandling can be done by implementing your own [`ExceptionFilterAttribute`](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/error-handling/exception-handling). You can use this attribute to decorate all controllers which need an exception handling.

Basiclly, you override the `OnException` method and convert different exception types into status code and message.